# Spark object runtime error

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

while running the program in my local system getting error as 
MY ram size is 3GB , need solution

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: System memory 259522560 must be at least 471859200. Please increase heap size using the --driver-memory option or spark.driver.memory in Spark configuration.
    at org.apache.spark.memory.UnifiedMemoryManager$.getMaxMemory(UnifiedMemoryManager.scala:216)
    at org.apache.spark.memory.UnifiedMemoryManager$.apply(UnifiedMemoryManager.scala:198)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.create(SparkEnv.scala:330)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.createDriverEnv(SparkEnv.scala:174)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.createSparkEnv(SparkContext.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:432)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2313)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$6.apply(SparkSession.scala:868)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$6.apply(SparkSession.scala:860)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:860)
    at SparkCore.cartesianTransformation$.main(cartesianTransformation.scala:11)
    at SparkCore.cartesianTransformation.main(cartesianTransformation.scala)
```

Comment: How can we help you if you don't post anycode?

Answer (score 0):

It seems your spark driver is running in small memory try to increase the size of driver memory. 
You can use `--driver-memory 4g` to provide the memory size to driver.

Hope this helps!

Comment: can you see in the web UI how much of memory has been used ??

Comment: and try adding  -Xmx1024m -Xms512m in VM arguments